# 16.04 desktop icon backgrounds

Tags: icons, .desktop, colors, desktop-background, desktop-icons

Is it possible to change the background color of the Desktop Icons?

I have a light colored background image and cannot read the Names (white text) of the Icons for my document links on the Desktop.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you not tried icons themes?

Comment: @PRATAP Could you post an answer and ping me so I can upvote please?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to change your default icons theme.

1. The terminal way:

   - Add the official PPA using add apt repository command:

   Ex. I like the shadow icon theme, so we will take an example of that but of course, we can perform the same task for different themes:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons
   ```

   - Use the `apt-get update` command to update your repositories:

     sudo apt-get update
   - Now install the icon pack with the `install` command:

     sudo apt-get install shadow-icon-theme
2. The GUI (easy) way:

   - Download your preferred icon theme 
     [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/).
   - Navigate to your home directory `cd "home-directory-name"` and look for `.icons` folder (as this is hidden folder you may need to use: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or run the command `ls -a` when you are in the home directory.)
     Please note that it is possible to not have this folder, so make one and name it `.icons`.

Note that in both ways you will need to use Unity tweak tool to enable the icon theme under the appearance tab.

The process is more or less the same for changing themes, cursor, and dock.